# How to replace upper case with lower case using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace upper case letter in variable name with lower case letter and add space

For example:

`NotImplementedException` should be `Not implemented exception`
`UnhandledException` should be `Unhandled exception`

Comment: In what programming language ? Most of the time, regexes alone won't allow you to do this, you'lle need to run some code on occurrence

Comment: language is C# but i need regex :(

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use a regular expression?  Most of the time people ask this kind of question, they are making assumptions about the kind of answer they need.

Comment: cause regex is configuration parameter, system is live and i need to do this without installation of a new version

Comment: @AndrewAylett The question is useful to me (though the lack of an actual answer is not) because I'm using VS search/replace, which uses the same regex.  This would have avoided large numbers of "repeat find, convert case" keystroke sequences.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since you did not specify a language, I'll give an example in C#. I am sure your language will offer something like it.

```
String s = "NotImplementedException";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\B[A-Z]", m => " " + m.ToString().ToLower());
// s = "Not implemented exception"
```

Comment: A better C# version of this answer, which would support ANY upper case letter (even accented ones) would be : `String s = "NotImplementedException";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\B\p{Lu}", m => " " + m.ToString().ToLower());`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in sed with single command:

```
$ echo "NotImplementedException" | sed 's/\B[A-Z]/ \l&/g'
Not implemented exception
```

But support for `\l` (and `\u`, `\L`, `\U` and `\E`) is rare among Regex implementations in different languages. I'm only sure that Perl has this implemented.

Comment: Agreed:  \L, \U et al are the only ways to do this in a regex that I know of, but like you say, quite rare. I've only noticed it in JGSoft products and Perl: `echo "NotImplementedException" | perl -pe 's/(\B[A-Z])/ \l$1/g'`

Answer (score -7):

@Ignacio, I beg to differ.  Certainly this is not something which can be done in one statement with plain regular expressions.  But the sed command:

```
sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)C/\1 c/g' infile.txt
```

will replace all occurrences of 'C' with ' c' when the 'C' is immediately preceded by a letter.  All OP has to do is make 26 variants of this, which might be tedious.  And getting the condition under which the case is altered might be difficult too but that's always the case with using regular expressions for global search-and-replace.

Comment: Was this a serious answer, or were you just arguing with Ignacio?