# How to replace lower case with upper case using regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the string a with full of lower case. I tried to use the following Expression to replace lower case with upper case but it does not work as I want. How can I turn the lower case into upper case in string a?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string a = "pieter was a small boy";
a = Regex.Replace(a, @"\B[A-Z]", m => " " + m.ToString().ToUpper());
```

Comment: is `a.ToUpper()` not enough???

Comment: What are you trying to do ? convert whole string to upper case ?

Comment: I think OP gone through this [**`link`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3235446/1577396) and cant invert the solution for `ToUpper()`.

Comment: a.ToUpper() can solve the problem i guess

Comment: All the people who downvoted because "a.ToUpper() is not enough??" need to open their minds a little bit beyond the use case posted here. I came to this post from Google because I'm writing a source code conversion utility and I need a regex that will find a declaration, then a property accessor, then the first following character and upper-case it. No, ToUpper is not good enough.

Answer (score 11):

You have two problems here:

1. Your pattern needs to use `\b` instead of `\B`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex) for more info.
2. Since  your string is in lowercase and your pattern only matches uppercase (`[A-Z]`) you need to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to make your code work.

---

```
string a = "pieter was a small boy";
var regex = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
a = regex.Replace(a, m=>m.ToString().ToUpper());
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Pieter Was A Small Boy
```

Comment: "two problems" heh heh

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to convert all the characters in the string to upper case then simply do [string.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx)

```
string upperCasea = a.ToUpper();
```

If you want to do a case insensitive replace then use [`Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator, RegexOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
a = Regex.Replace(a, 
                  @"\b[A-Z]", 
                  m => " " + m.ToString().ToUpper(), 
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He specifically asks for the use case of a regex. I think that would automatically imply that he wants to ToUpper on a capture group, or at least something to do with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expression as you wanted,

```
a = Regex.Replace(a, @"\b[a-z]", m => m.ToString().ToUpper());
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235446/1577396)

Comment: That regex adds space as well. That isn't what the OP wants

Comment: removed the space, is it ok now? @Cthulhu

Comment: You need to change the `\B` to `\b`, too.

Answer (score -1):

```
Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\]", "").ToUpperInvariant();
```

Answer (score -1):

It works fine for you :

```
string a = "pieter was a small boy";
a = a.ToUpper();
```