# How to tell a ASPX uppercase converter to ignore certain parts of string for conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, textfield

I am trying to fill in an online form for printing out business cards. The online form is ASPX. I am using their service and I do not have control over the backend.

One of the text fields is being force converted to uppercase in the preview (whats seen on the preview will be finally printed). I am presuming there is a string.toupper or text-transform that is being used to force convert string to uppercase.

Is there a way to pass a string that someone tells the converter to ignore certain parts for conversion?
For example:

Current:
text-field: Dr. Joe Smith  --> preview: DR. JOE SMITH

I want:
text-field: Dr. Joe Smith --> preview: Dr. JOE SMITH

Comment: I think you can use RegEx for converting to upper only some parts of the string, following a pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235403/how-to-replace-upper-case-with-lower-case-using-regex

Comment: I am not sure if  I explained correctly. I do not have access to backend of the form, which means I cannot run RegEx. I am looking for a way to pass some pattern inside the string that conveys to string.toupper/text-.transform to ignore certain parts

Comment: Depending on the char set and encoding you might be able to pass a symbol that looks like an "r" but is not. Uppercase conversion doesn't have effect on certain symbols. However this is incredibly hacky.

Comment: @derloopkat, I ended up doing that. Found a special character that most resembles the character I wanted.